# How to display a WMTS map layer using SharpMap?

Tags: c#, sharpmap

I want to use sharpmap WMTS online map data to be loaded on the desktop,
Use Google access to a lot of, but all have no, excuse me somebody know sharpmap official document where there is?

i don't know how to do this.

I want to use sharpmap WMTS online map data to be loaded on the desktop,
Use Google access to a lot of, but all have no, excuse me somebody know sharpmap official document where there is?

i don't know how to do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.